# ¿Por qué me marca Error para ingresar a WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

Tengo una duda, trato de ingresar a WordPress como administrador y me arroja el siguiente error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot use object of type WP_Error as array in /home/IS/public_html/wp-content/plugins/themeisle-companion/vendor/codeinwp/themeisle-sdk/class-themeisle-sdk-feedback-translate.php on line 804
```

¿Saben a qué se deba o cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: Desactiva ese plugin o elimínalo y busca un equivalente.

Answer (score 1):

Accede a través de FTP o cPanel y renombrar la carpeta del plugins, puede ser algún tipo de error de compatibilidad de php, te recomiendo actualizar los plugins y la versión de WordPress.